# How to get a list of color values between two given ones?

Tags: colors

How to get a list of color values between two given ones? For example, I have #ab7878 and #da9933, what if I want the first color to be gradually transformed into the second color, how could I get those values in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = 0xab7878;
var b = 0xda9933;

while(b > a)
{
  a = a + 0xFF;
  console.log(a.toString(16));
}
```

Full output:
[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/YXugzi8R)

Comment: WOOOOOOW!!!! That's something! Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Can you, please, explain a bit why was it exactly plus 0xFF and not, say, plus 0x22 or 0x00?

Comment: It can be any value. I just chose a higher value than 1 so the length would decline. Probabøy should check the distance between the values and pick the incrementvalue from thar.

Comment: But... wait a moment, will it really be a smooth change from the first color into the second? I mean, will it really be a gradient?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by incrementing the values for R, G and B at the same time.

```
#4477AA
#5588BB
#6699CC
#77AADD
#88BBEEE
```